# Using argument of function in Node's module async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I learn Node.js and doing a small site guided by [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs).

I reached to place where there using module [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Displaying_data/Home_page).
This is code

```
async.parallel({
    book_count: function(callback) {
        Book.countDocuments({}, callback); // Pass an empty object as match condition to find all documents of this collection
    },
    book_instance_count: function(callback) {
        BookInstance.countDocuments({}, callback);
    },
    book_instance_available_count: function(callback) {
        BookInstance.countDocuments({status:'Available'}, callback);
    },
    author_count: function(callback) {
        Author.countDocuments({}, callback);
    },
    genre_count: function(callback) {
        Genre.countDocuments({}, callback);
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Local Library Home', error: err, data: results });
});
```

};

This code count number documents  in the database.
I don't understand what is argument "callback". There have  nothing sent  in these properties "book_count, book_instance_count, author_count, etc.." but all of these function   work excellent.
Please, explain to me , what is  odd argument "callback" and how to use it.

Comment: If it answered your question, please read the following so you could mark the answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Callback function

> A callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action.

```
function greeting(name) {
  alert('Hello ' + name);
}

function processUserInput(callback) {
  var name = prompt('Please enter your name.');
  callback(name);
}

processUserInput(greeting);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Callback_function